# Как сбэкапить снэпшот серверного диска на Amazon S3?

Tags: резервное-копирование

Есть старенький сервер, который собираемся снести, предварительно сохранив все данные «на всякий случай» в [Amazon S3](http://aws.amazon.com/s3/).

Как лучше это сделать?

Начал делать это с помощью [duplicity](http://duplicity.nongnu.org/), но что-то долго это происходит, уже почти сутки.

**Upd.** за 21 час, в итоге, бэкап полностью прошел: все файлы благополучно перенесены в букет на S3. Duplicity подходящий инструмент, но заточен больше на постоянные инкрементальные бэкапы. Успешно использую его на нескольких рабочих проектах. **Вопрос остаётся открытым:** что лучше для разового слива снэпшота жесткого диска на AWS S3?

Answer (score 1):

mysqldump tar gzip и много других полезных вещей, определитесь, что бэкапить нужно

Comment: Что бэкапить? Диск. Жёсткий. Одна штука.

Comment: Ну так duplicity, как я понял из описания, это tar, rsync в одном флаконе.Так и используйте на здоровье

Comment: Ага, спасибо, посоветовали.. Видимо, с duplicity вы дела не имели. Так каким ценным личным опытом тут делитесь, я что-то не понимаю?

Comment: Да, действительно не имел.